XGboost classification order of features influencing predictions
I am creating a UFC fight prediction model using xgboost classification, trained on a dataset that includes the stats of 2 fighters and the result of the fight. After training a model, I defined a function where I can just input fighters names and it gets their stats from a fighter stats data set, and feeds that into the model to predict who will win. However, when trying to make new predictions (for example: xgb_ufc("Vicente Luque", "Themba Gorimbo") and xgb_ufc("Themba Gorimbo", "Vicente Luque"), the predictions are different (in both, the first fighter is chosen to "win")). I've tried methods to reduce overfitting, but it seems the order in which the fight stats/features are inputted still affects the prediction. Does anyone know why this is and how to fix it?

Welcome to Cross Validated! Indeed, this sounds weird. My suspicion is that it is a bug in your code.

Thanks for the reply Dave, I think so too, but I haven't found any glaring errors yet. I'm pretty new to machine learning, so do you think that another possibility is the model being "unsure" as theres not a very clear "winner"?

what does your training dataset look like? For example, does the first fighter always win in that dataset? Even if you avoided this error, you may be interested in "data augmentation"; i.e. create a copy of your dataset with the order of fighters switched and feed both in as training data. But if you give us more details about your training dataset we can be more helpful.

Thanks for the reply John! I trained it on 2 data sets to try and fix it, the first one had the winner of the fight (either red or blue) and then the following columns were the red fighters overall stats followed by the blue fighters overall stats. The second dataset I split the first one into the red and blue stats and took the difference (a suggestion from gpt) with the same winners column and trained it on the differences. One more thing I forgot to specify is that this error doesn't happen for every single prediction. I will look more into data augmentation though, thank you for the help!

Sounds like a programming bug, either with your code or (less likely) XGboost. Debugging this isn’t an on-topic question here. If you decide to ask the question elsewhere, be advised that you’ll need to share a minimal reproducible example.
